# Fp growth using rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

Fp growth operator is returning "no rules found ". I used nominal to binary , Fp growth and create association rule operators to apply fp growth algorithm on iris.csv file using RapidMiner.I didn't understood why it is returning "no rules found". I need your help .

Answer (score 0):

From your description I would say you just forgot to discretize the example set before transforming it to binominal.
Have a look at the tutorial process in the help text of the Create Association Rules Operator.